# Basic or Digest Authentication using OAuth Provider

Tags: facebook, oauth, basic-authentication, digest-authentication

I need to build a server with Basic or Digest authentication. I can not use any other authentication, this is my requirement and a limitation of the client applications that I am using (Microsoft miniredirector, Mac OS X Finder, iCal, Microsoft Office, LibreOffice, davfs2, etc).

I do not want the user to create any new accounts in my system. Instead I want him to utilize his existing Facebook, Google+, LinkedIn or any other account. However as far as I know this systems require the application to show the login web page, which is not possible in my case.

Is it possible to implement Basic or Digest authentication using Facebook, Google+, LinkedIn or any other social network API?

Comment: Do you HAVE to use basic or digest auth?  If not you could just build your app to use oAuth along with one or many of the social providers you listed.  Rather than checking for basic or digest auth, you would check that the user is authenticated via that social provider.

Comment: @cdbconcepts How do I check that user is authenticated without displaying web page for user to login? Mac OS X Finder, iCal, davfs2 and Mini-redirector can not display any web pages.